# Existence of square root of identity map on the circle

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

I am self-studying covering spaces. I am stuck on the following problem.

Does there exists a continuous map $f:S^1\to S^1$ such that $f(x)^2 = x$ for all $x\in S^1$?

I am trying to show the non-existence of this kind of map by lifting it to some covering spaces but was not able to succeed.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am taking $(f(x))^2$ not $f\circ f(x)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $f(x)^2 = x$, then $(\times 2) \circ f_* = \mbox{Id}_{\mathbb{Z}}$ is the induced action on the fundamental group, but the $\times 2$ map is not injective, so it can't possible compose with something to give the identity on $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: What is  $(\times 2)$ map? From where $(\times 2)$ map comes? are you lifting identity?

Comment: The $\times 2$ map is just the map $n \mapsto 2n$ on the integers. If $g \colon S^1 \to S^1$ is the function $g(x) = x^2$, then the induced map $g_\ast$ is the $\times 2$ map.